# Render a large amount of complex HTML

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react component where I have to render something like 600 children components (and the number will increase slowly). Each of these inner component are pretty big and complex (they have even a svg in it). Also, I have to be able to filter them. I used keys everywhere to be sure not to waste re-render but it's anyway very heavy. I'm wondering which would be the most performant way to do this. I can't paginate unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**That's too much for JavaScript / React to handle on the client at once, your best bets are - server render and split work.**

---

1. Server side render first `N`
2. Lazy load the rest `600 - N` and render incrementally
3. Implement `shouldComponentUpdate`
4. Use `keys` (as you've done)

You can also use [Fixed Data Table](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) if it fits your concept.